# vb.net search in access database

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a basic question. I have a access database where I have a List2 with 2 columns. I have a inputbox where I scan barcode number and I want to search this barcode number in column 1 (name header - Zak) if find this barcode in column then show me from column 2 (name header Cisl) value on the same row where is barcode. I have a part of code and I dont known how continue. Thank you for help

```
Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click
    Dim barcode As String = Nothing
    Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow

    barcode = InputBox("Naskenujte čárový kód ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
    If Len(Trim(barcode)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    'Vytvoreni dotazu

    foundRows = SdfDataSet.Tables("List2").Select("[Zak] = '" & barcode & "'")


    If foundRows IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Nenalezeno")
    Else
        MsgBox("Zákaznické číslo: " & barcode & foundRows(0)("Cisl"))
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is image database https://s4.postimg.org/8qulca9e5/source.png

Comment: You're basically asking how to query a database with a `WHERE` clause.  That is basic data access and something you can read about in a multitude of places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this if I understand your question:

```
 'Get the Row with the barcode.
 Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow
 foundRows = DataSet1.Tables("List1").Select("[Zak] = '" & barcode & "'")

If foundRow IsNot Nothing Then
    'If not Found do something here or not.    
Else
   'If found output the first found rows Column2
    MsgBox("Zákaznické číslo: " & barcode & foundRow(0)("Column2"))
End If
```

**Note** : Replace *Column2* With the column name.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to have already pulled all the rows from the table in the db into the dataset. Hugely inefficient. As per jmcilhinney's comment, you should query the db using the barcode in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi, sorry nothing happen. I update a source code at the top look.

Comment: I scan barcode to input box and based on this value search in first column on the list2 this value. If i find value I want to show value from first column and value from second column on the same row.

Comment: As peterG mentioned you would have to pull  all the rows from the DB using  this approach, have you filled your DataSet?

Comment: Why inefficient ? I want only search value in column and show value from coresponding value on the same row.. why is it problem?

Comment: @Filip You've not really shown us enough code, or enough context, to decide one way or another. For instance, if your dataset functions as a lookup, then a valid approach would be to populate the dataset once on startup of the app, and then search it when you need it in the way you describe. I suspect you're not doing that though. Another thing that concerns me is the design of your dataset. No pk-fk relationship defined. This can be appropriate, but it's generally not.

Comment: . . contd: Finally you're using Access which further complicates the efficiency argument, because all the processing takes place locally anyway. Careful indexing is essential to mitigate this.